# Could we make two versions of the "gender" tag?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

I'd like to be able to put different tags on these two types of questions:

1. The question has to do with distinctions between masculine/feminine nouns or pronouns.  Examples: [Gender of objective pronouns and demonstratives with no explicit object](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24184/9385), [¿Es más correcto decir "Nos lo pasamos muy bien" o "Nos la pasamos muy bien"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23434/9385)
2. The question has to do with different genders of *people*.  For example, mothers and fathers, considered together in one group, become "padres" which technically is masculine but functions as a mixed gender group.  Examples: [¿Por qué no existe la palabra "marida"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23637/9385), [How is gender ambiguity handled by native speakers?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24273/9385)

Could we split the tag up into two slightly different tags?

---

Responses to comments

1. Charlie's question today about a masculine form of *musa* would fit well into type 1 -- which by the way has to do with nouns too, not just pronouns.
2. Rome wasn't built in a day, and if we did differentiate, I wouldn't be expecting other people to do the retagging (unless they were particularly interested).  Clearly, this is something I'm interested in, and would be wanting to chip away at gradually.

   The most painless way to make a tag split is to notice which of the two new tags is more common, call it "new tag A," and transfer all the old tags to "new-tag-A."  Gradually, one or more volunteers could check all the questions with that tag and switch them if necessary to "new-tag-B."  In this case, the more common would be my type 1, of course.
3. The potential benefit is that it would be much easier for those interested, now and in the future, to find questions about gender issues (as that term is called in English).  In addition, this branch of inquiry would be nourished by the existence of a tag.  This would be an opportunity for our site to b a pioneer, thus drawing more attention among the general online community.  This could help the site grow.
4. Regarding this sentence:

> Finally, would we need to re-tag all of our questions with the género to use the new ones (right now you propose to slit in two, but in the near or far future someone could come with a new use case for a slightly different differentiation, and we might have multiple gender tags).

(a) I can't imagine what additional splits could occur, but if they do, well, we could cross that bridge when we come to it;

(b) What's to prevent people from using a similar argument in *any* tag split proposal that might be put forward?

I think I saw somewhere once, sorry to be so vague, the number five used as a practical minimum to justify the existence of a tag.  Here are some questions that might fit with the version of a gender tag having to do with gender studies, gender politics, and sexism-related questions (as opposed to strict grammar discussions).  Note some of these might not be a perfect fit but here are the candidates I was able to identify:

[How is gender ambiguity handled by native speakers?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24273/9385)

[¿Es posible ocultar mi género en Internet al hablar en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23963/9385)

[¿Por qué no existe la palabra "marida"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23637/9385)

[¿Por qué el género masculino suele dominar a la hora de referirse a colectivos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16773/9385) (not very sure about this one)

[¿Es correcto usar "@" para significar femenino/masculino?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15010/9385)

[¿Se debe decir jefe o jefa al referirse a una persona de sexo femenino?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3195/9385)

[¿Existe un equivalente masculino de "musa"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24462/9385)

[¿Cuál sería el opuesto etimológico de "feminismo"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24450/9385)

Final comment: "Lenguaje inclusivo" is a great idea, somewhat separate but related to the above proposal, and eventually it might include questions have nothing to do with gender.  For example, one could ask about modern, respectful regional synonyms for gay and lesbian, and "lenguaje inclusivo" would fit great in there.  Also, I find some modern terminology such as "cis" confusing, and questions related to that would fit well too.  In addition we could explore terminology related to disability vs. differences -- maybe there are some new options available now.

Comment: Could you show some examples on when to use each one of those?

Comment: @fedorqui - Puse algunos.  Hay mas en la etiqueta "genero".

Comment: Gracias. Nótese que también tenemos [tag:neutralidad-de-género].

Answer (score 4):

**I don't see the need and I don't see the benefit of it.**

It could have helped to visualize it better if you had propose the name of the tags, but even if we say [género-personas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g%c3%a9nero-personas) and [género-pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g%c3%a9nero-pronombres) the distinction is a little bit artificial and unnecessary to me.

A question about if I should use the "la or lo" pronoun and if I can say "jueza and presidenta" are of course different, but I just think that those questions should be tagged with other additional tags (like [género](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g%c3%a9nero) and [pronombres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombres) or [vocabulario-técnico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%c3%a9cnico)) instead of a more specific gender tag.

Splitting the [género](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g%c3%a9nero) in that way could make the resulting tags a little bit more difficult to use.

Finally, would we need to re-tag all of our questions with the [género](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g%c3%a9nero) to use the new ones (right now you propose to slit in two, but in the near or far future someone could come with a new use case for a slightly different differentiation, and we might have multiple gender tags). Not that we should shy away from this effort if we think that it is worth it, but I don't think we have a clear benefit that would justify that effort.

Comment: De hecho también tenemos [tag:neutralidad-de-género].

Comment: Gracias por la puntualización. Actualmente hay solo 5 preguntas con ese tag. Ese tag tiene poco en su guía de uso y definición "Preguntas sobre neutralidad de género y lenguaje inclusivo." Me parece un poco como tener tags "género-masculino" y "género-femenino". No está mal tener tags tan específicos, pero me pregunto si con "género" a secas no bastaría, o si algunos tags deberían ser otra cosa (como "lenguaje-inclusivo") y acompañar al tag "género" en las preguntas. Posiblemente hay más en el lenguaje inclusivo que el género.

Comment: Bien visto. Comenté porque en el chat walen me hizo notar este hecho. Fijándome con más detenimiento, veo que [apenas dos preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutralidad-de-g%C3%A9nero+-g%C3%A9nero) usan [tag:neutralidad-de-género] y no [tag:género]. Me resulta interesante la propuesta de mencionar "lenguaje inclusivo", si bien puede degenerar en una ultracorrección que no considero pertinente en Spanish.SE (véase [Fundéu sobre el lenguaje inclusivo](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/lenguaje-inclusivo-6151/))

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo